# Insert NULL for date /or time in Postgres when blank using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm inserting records read from a file in date /or time field in Postgres.
Many of the date/or time fields are blank in file. I want null to be inserted for the corresponding table fields. Postgres table col for date /or time is defined as date/ or time respectively.
Using the query as below.
I'm getting error :
psycopg2.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid input syntax for type date: "          "
Any directions as to where lies the problem will be helpful.

```
INSERT INTO userbasic
(name, create_date, owner_id, adsp, special,
 oper, revoke, grpacc, pwd_interval, pwd_date,
 programmer, defgrp_id, lastjob_time, lastjob_date, install_data)
VALUES 
(%s, NULLIF(%s,'')::date, %s, %s, %s, 
%s, %s, %s, %s, NULLIF(%s,'')::date, 
%s, %s,NULLIF(%s,'')::time, NULLIF(%s,'')::date, %s)
```

Expect the records with no value for date/ or time col to be inserted to table with NULL.

Comment: My guess the blank values that are being supplied are more along the lines of `'    '`, more then one space. Your `NULLIF(%s,'')` is only going to catch true empty strings.  A `print(len(variable))` will help verify this. You will need to normalize the data to empty strings, either on the Python side or the SQL side.

Comment: You might also want to look at Postgres log to see what is actually hitting database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adrian Klaver, many thanks for your inputs.
I used the below code and NULLIF(%s,'')::date for the corresponding field in VALUES clause. This solved the problem.

```
contain_space = True
for i in raw_record[14:24]:
    if i != ' ':
        contain_space = False
        break
if contain_space:
   self.create_date = ''
else:
   self.create_date = raw_record[14:24]
```

Answer (score 1):

You here are passing "STRING" as value in date-time field.

To insert "NULL" in this field you can use "NULLIF()" function([example here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-nullif/)). This function will convert empty string to NULL. Now, you need to convert this to "date-time" type, for this you can use "[to_date()](https://www.rudderstack.com/guides/queries-casting-postgresql/#:%7E:text=String%20to%20Date%20and%20Timestamp,to_timestamp(text%2C%20text)%20.)" function or just typecast it.

This query might help:

```
INSERT INTO userbasic (
name, create_date, owner_id, adsp, special, oper, revoke, grpacc,
pwd_interval, pwd_date, programmer, defgrp_id, lastjob_time, lastjob_date,
install_data) 
 VALUES (
      %s,NULLIF(%s,'')::date,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,
      %s,NULLIF(%s,'')::date,%s,%s,NULLIF(%s,'')::time,NULLIF(%s,'')::date,
      CASE WHEN NULLIF(%s, '') = '' THEN NULL ELSE to_date(%s, 'YYYY-MM-DD') END
)
```

*you might need to use to_timestamp() function to convert a string in a specific time format*

Comment: 1) Passing a string is permissable: `select '2023-05-04'::date; 05/04/2023` 2) Read the OP's question, in particular the query. It is already using `NULLIF`.  3) Change the 'answer' to one that is actually relevant or delete it.